# In an Angular-router Resolver, how can one distinguish between a page refresh or initial visit versus a subsequent in-session visit

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router-guards

In an angular-router resolver's `resolve` method, is there a way to distinguish between (for lack of a better term) *hard* navigation (page-refreshes and first-visits within a session) and *soft* navigation (subsequent visits within a session by forward or backward traversal)?

Here's my scenario. I always need to fetch data from the server for *hard* navigation and I only occasionally need to fetch data from the server for *soft* navigation. More typically however for *soft* navigation I merely perform other tasks which don't entail interaction with the server but which do use parameter values from the route.

Comment: I think the best approach then is to check whether you have the necessary data before you fetch it on resolve.

Comment: @AvinKavish Checking to see if the required data is already in memory before initiating a fetch from the server is similar to how I was thinking of solving this problem. One could use the server-parameters portion of the route as a key to the local memory store. However, I wonder if Angular provides some other mechanism.